# Google Colab not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have an issue with Google Colab. When I want to make a new Python3 Notebook, the new page which just opened is not loading, due to the fact that I'm logged in my Google Acount.
What should I do?
Thank you for your help.

new page situation
[image: new page situation]

Comment: Does this error persist in an incognito window? (Often, extensions are the cause of such issues.) Also worth checking if there are any errors on the [Javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

Comment: Yes, it persists.

Comment: What's reported in the [Javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)?

Comment: Sometimes these are ad blockers. Have to disable them to get it working.

Comment: I disabled Ad Blocker, but still not working.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: Me too, It is very cumbersome//May be it is related the factory reset? 10 mins before... I did a factory reset

Answer (score 2):

Open the inspect element browser, select the console tag and check the errors, warnings, info. Trying to remove all the add-ons is the best way to check. Some add-ons work in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. What i did was, deleted all the browsing data from the date i started using google colab. I don't know why but this actually worked. I hope this answer help some